# Does $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^3 \sin x $ exist?

Tags: limits

Having trouble asnswering "Does $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^3 \sin x $ exist?."

Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $x=2\pi n$ and $x=\pi n+\pi/2$ to find sub-sequences with two different limits.

Answer (score 1):

No, certainly not. You can find subsequences which tend to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^3$ gets monotonically and
unboundedly large,
and
$\sin(x)$ oscillates
so that it is
infinitely often
$\pm 1$,
so, no.